# A simple calculation with text box in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 

            <html>
            <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>jquery Mobile Web App</title>
            <link href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a3/jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a3/jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

            <script>

            $(document).ready(function(){
                var lens = $('#lens').val();

            //var fullframe = 0;  // initialize the sum to zero
             var fullframe = 600/lens;
                $('#fullframe').val(fullframe);
            var fullframe = 600/lens;
            var apsccanon = 600/(lens*1.6);
            var apscnikon = 600/(lens*1.5);
            $('#fullframe').val(fullframe);
            $('#apsccanon').val(apsccanon);
            $('#apscnikon').val(apscnikon);

            });
            </script>

            </head> 
            <body> 

            <div data-role="page" id="page">
                <div data-role="header">
                    <h1>Rule 600</h1>
                </div>
                <div data-role="content">   
                    Rule 600 Calculator
                </div>


                <div>
                <form action="">
             Lens:<br>
            <input type='text' id='fullframe' />
            <br>
            Full Frame:<br>
            <input type='text' id='fullframe' value=""/>
            <br>
             APSC Canon:<br>
            <input type='text' id='apsccanon' value="" />
            <br>
             APSC Nikon:<br>
            <input type='text' id='apscnikon' value="" />
            <br>
            </form> 
            </div>


                <div data-role="footer">
                    <h4>Footer</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>

            </body>
            </html>
```

Trying to develop a simple mobile calculator for camera lenses in Dreamweaver 5.5. The calculations are quite simple but I'm unable to make it work. Need some help.

Comment: You need to run your calculation when one of those inputs is amended. Try using the `change` or `keyup` events. Also, where is the `#lens` element?

Comment: _unable to make it work_ .. What are you trying to obtain and what are you getting instead?

Comment: There are four text boxes. First text box takes the lens input as number say 200, the other three text boxes gives the calculated output in numbers. The output gives infinity!

Answer (score 0):

You have duplicate `id`. Every element should have `unique` `IDs`

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I guess this is an answer to OP question, Once he will do this and change the ID in j accordingly.. Everything will run.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the duplicate id. After changing it the results shows infinity!

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve.? Please elaborate that.

Comment: And please update the code of your question with the changed IDs

Answer (score 0):

You should decide when the calculation should take place, it could be when the value in the `lens` field changes, or when you press some button or some other logic that you decide.

This is how you can bind some operations to an event (in this case `keyup` applied to the `lens` field (pay attention to the `id` of the `lens` field)

```
 $("#lens").on("keyup", function () {
        var lens = $(this).val();
        //var fullframe = 0;  // initialize the sum to zero
        var fullframe = 600 / lens;
        $('#fullframe').val(fullframe);
        var fullframe = 600 / lens;
        var apsccanon = 600 / (lens * 1.6);
        var apscnikon = 600 / (lens * 1.5);
        $('#fullframe').val(fullframe);
        $('#apsccanon').val(apsccanon);
        $('#apscnikon').val(apscnikon);
    });
```

You may want to add some controls regarding the values inserted in the lens field (for example `0` will populate all the computed fields to `NaN` due to a division-by-zero).

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/sczomaqs/

Comment: Thanks. Tried this code. The output text boxes show nothing. Every time I put a lens value the output text boxes should automatically show the calculated value.

Comment: make sure you include jQuery and that your lens field has the correct id ("id=lens"). I updated the answer with an example.

Comment: Yes it is working in fiddle. But not in Dreamweaver.